# Local Notifications are not working on physical device after closing and opening the app

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I'm working on a SwiftUI app.

The `Local Notifications` are working if the app was `opened by Xcode`, are running even after pulling out the cable if the app wasn't restated.

After I `close the app` and open it again, the notification are not working anymore.

Notification Handler:

```
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

final class NotificationHandler {

    public static func scheduleLocalNotification(title: String, body: String, timeInterval: Double = 0.1) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
}
```

}

How I use it:

```
    private func scheduleNotificationsIfNecessary(notifications: [Notification]) {
        let newNotificationsIDs = notificationAppStorage.checkIfNotificationExists(ids: notifications.map { $0.id })
    
        newNotificationsIDs.forEach { notificationID in
            notificationAppStorage.addNotification(notificationID)
    }
    
        newNotificationsIDs.forEach { notificationID in
            if let newNotification = findNotificationByID(notificationID) {
                NotificationHandler.scheduleLocalNotification(
                    title: newNotification.symbol,
                    body: getNotificationBody(notification: newNotification.notification, profit: newNotification.profit, volume: newNotification.volume) )
            }
        }
    }
```